# PPS 2010 YTD vs. calculated measure aggregation fails (with pics)

Tags: ssas, performancepoint

I have 2 measures:

1. Sales Value
2. Sales Value LY (calculated measure)

and a time filter with single month member and YTD formula.

If i make simple PerformancePoint report like so:

[image: Report definitions]

It shows up correctly like this when single month is selected from the time filter:

[image: Report with single month selected]

But when i try the YTD formula from the time filter:

[image: Sales LY lost]

the calculated measure is lost from the report.

Any ideas?

Comment: Could you show the definition of your YTD calculation?

Comment: Using the simple YTD, from the code samples here: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff701696.aspx

Comment: How is the `Sales Value LY` defined?

Comment: Theres calculated NULL column in the datasource named Sales Amount LY, which is then scoped:

`scope ({Measures.[Sales Value LY]});  
this = (PARALLELPERIOD([Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].[Month], 12,[Time].[Year -  Month -  Date].CURRENTMEMBER),[Measures].[SALES AMOUNT]);  
end scope; 
`

Answer (score 0):

I would try to change the `ParallelPeriod(Month, 12)` to `ParallelPeriod(Year, 1)` in your measure definition:

```
scope ({Measures.[Sales Value LY]});
   this = (PARALLELPERIOD(
            [Time].[Year - Month - Date].[Year],
            1,
            [Time].[Year - Month - Date].CURRENTMEMBER
          ),
          [Measures].[SALES AMOUNT]);
end scope;
```

`ParallelPeriod` only works properly if the current period is below or at the level stated as the first argument.

**EDIT**

Maybe changing the expression like proposed at http://sqlblog.com/blogs/mosha/archive/2007/01/13/multiselect-friendly-mdx-for-calculations-looking-at-current-coordinate.aspx would help:

```
scope ({Measures.[Sales Value LY]});
   this = Sum(EXISTING [Time].[Year - Month - Date].[Day].Members,
            (PARALLELPERIOD(
              [Time].[Year - Month - Date].[Year],
              1,
              [Time].[Year - Month - Date].CURRENTMEMBER
            ),
            [Measures].[SALES AMOUNT]
            )
          );
end scope;
```

I was guessing the name of your day level, maybe you have to adapt that.

Comment: I don't see how this would help as the lowest granularity is day-level

Comment: I do not know how the YTD calculation of PerformancePoint is defined. Maybe this is an issue of calculation order: If the YTD calculation is applied first and then the `LY` calculation then the ParallelPeriod does not have a single `CurrentMember` and hence fails. But tis type of problem is difficult to solve without knowing the exact MDX statement executed and the calculation script of the cube. Another try could be to leave off the third argument of ParallelPeriod, i. e. use `(PARALLELPERIOD([Time].[Year - Month - Date].[Year], 1, )`.

Comment: the funny thing is that PPS re-writes different MDX query in the report, depending on the filters value if its a single value or time range :)

Answer (score 0):

Have a workaround thus:

built-in YTD semiadditive function in PPS time intelligence can be written also like this:

```
year.firstmonth.parent:year.month.parent
```

Dunno if the YTD function is buggy or whatnot, but this was the quick way to get the parallel YTD values..